# Intellij ClassNotFoundException packageName.main

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

I have imported some files into new directory, and created new setup for my java project. Now, it looks like that:

```
--src
----ex1
-------Main.java [package ex1]
----ex2
-------Main.java [package ex2]
----ex3
-------Main.java [package ex3]
```

Now, I am trying to run Main.java from folder `ex3` in my Intellij, and it throws me an error of :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ex3.Main

It works fine if I run it from terminal. My `ex3/Main.java` has `package ex3` on top of the file. Where is the issue?

Comment: I'd clean and rebuild.  It's certainly something you've done wrong - IntelliJ is pretty smart.

Comment: @duffymo, I've rebuilded it and I have error in 'package ex3' - does not correspond to file path

Comment: Believe IntelliJ.  Look at the source and output class arrangement.  It's not in the right place, even though you think it is.